# NaNs when changing kind

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have written a fairly simple algorithm for solving a linear system Ax=b. I have a parameter `rkind` that defines kind of my real variables.
Setting `rkind=8` creates no problems, but `rkind=kind(0.e0)` outputs `NaNs` in my solution. I changed the initialisation with `rkind` so I don't understand where the problem is.
I'm quite new to Fortran90, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide your code in a form of a [mcve].

Comment: `kind(0.e0)` will probably yield a different result than 8. First of all, it all depends on your compiler, so it is a bad idea to rely on magic numbers like 8 in this case. Furthermore, 8 is usually the kind number of double precision, while `0.e0` is usually a single precision literal.

Comment: Maybe SELECTED_REAL_KIND or similar for integer is what you want to consider?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I had made the stupid mistake of imposing a desired tolerance which exceeded single precision, while using single precision variables.